# jquery refactor: traversing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is some awesome code I'd like to make better.

```
select: function(event, ui)      
  {
  jQuery(this).siblings('div.hidden_fields').children('.poly_id').val(ui.item.user)
}
```

It is part of a `select` in jquery UI autocomplete.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see no problem with it. Also, it's very hard to tell without seeing your markup / DOM tree.

Comment: I love down voters. you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
jQuery('div.hidden_fields .poly_id',jQuery(this).parent()).val(...);
```

Remember you can always provide a context to a jQuery Selector

```
jQuery("someselector", context)
```